Gradient layer on UiView
I am trying to provide gradient layer to the View on created XIB. I have to give gradient colors with combination of 5 colors. But unfortunately gradient is not working.
These are colors array:-
let colors = [UIColor(red: 255.0, green: 252.0, blue: 252.0, alpha: 0).cgColor, UIColor(red: 126, green: 125, blue: 125, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 197.0, green: 195.0, blue: 195.0, alpha: 0.62).cgColor, UIColor(red: 126.0, green: 125.0, blue: 125.0, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 189.0, green: 189.0, blue: 189.0, alpha: 0.7).cgColor, UIColor(red: 255.0, green: 255.0, blue: 255.0, alpha: 0.0).cgColor]
Here i am applying gradient:-
self.separatorView.applyGradient(colors: colors,
locations: [0.0, 1.0],
direction: .leftToRight)
func applyGradient(colors: [Any]?, locations: [NSNumber]? = [0.0, 0.0], direction: Direction = .leftToRight) {
    
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = colors
    //gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.8, 1.0]

    switch direction {
    case .topToBottom:
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        
    case .bottomToTop:
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        
    case .leftToRight:
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        
        
    case .rightToLeft:
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    }
    
    self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}

I have to achieve gradient like mentioned in screenshot.


The numbers you pass to UIColor should be between 0 and 1, not 0 and 255. Did you write your own UIColor initialiser or something?

@Sweeper I am using the colors mentioned in figma design.

All the UIColor values needs to be between 0 and 1. So for each of theses values, divide them by 255.0: UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 252.0/255.0, blue: 252.0/255.0, alpha: 0) etc. Also, when is called applyGradient()? When it's called, what's the value of self.bounds and what's its value once rendered (use debug hierarchy view of XCode to see the frame), as there might be autolayout applied afterward.

Assuming you want an affect that gradients from the inside-outwards. You might just need to set the type on the gradientLayer:
gradient.type = .conic

